# How can I disable an <option> in a <select> based on its value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have a `<select>` with a number of `<option>`s. Each has a unique `value`. I need to disable an `<option>` with a given defined `value` (not `innerHTML`).

Anyone have an idea how?

Comment: I think the best solution for this is given in another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860103/hide-option-from-dropdown-2-when-selected-in-dropdown-1

Answer (score 131, accepted):

#### JavaScript, in 2022

You can use querySelectorAll, and forEach off of the resulting NodeList to do this same thing more easily in 2022.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#foo option").forEach(opt => {
    if (opt.value == "StackOverflow") {
        opt.disabled = true;
    }
});
```

Do be mindful of string-comparisons, however. 'StackOverflow' and 'stackoverflow' are not the same string. As such, you can call `.toLowerCase()` on strings before comparing, or even go with a case-insensitive regular expression comparison like the this:

```js
if ( /^stackoverflow$/i.test(option.value) ) {
  option.disabled = true;
}
```

#### Pure Javascript (2010)

With pure Javascript, you'd have to cycle through each option, and check the value of it individually.

```
// Get all options within <select id='foo'>...</select>
var op = document.getElementById("foo").getElementsByTagName("option");
for (var i = 0; i < op.length; i++) {
  // lowercase comparison for case-insensitivity
  (op[i].value.toLowerCase() == "stackoverflow") 
    ? op[i].disabled = true 
    : op[i].disabled = false ;
}
```

Without enabling non-targeted elements:

```
// Get all options within <select id='foo'>...</select>
var op = document.getElementById("foo").getElementsByTagName("option");
for (var i = 0; i < op.length; i++) {
  // lowercase comparison for case-insensitivity
  if (op[i].value.toLowerCase() == "stackoverflow") {
    op[i].disabled = true;
  }
}
```

###jQuery

With jQuery you can do this with a single line:

```
$("option[value='stackoverflow']")
  .attr("disabled", "disabled")
  .siblings().removeAttr("disabled");
```

Without enabling non-targeted elements:

```
$("option[value='stackoverflow']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

​
Note that this *is not* case insensitive. "StackOverflow" will not equal "stackoverflow". To get a case-insensitive match, you'd have to cycle through each, converting the value to a lower case, and then check against that:

```
$("option").each(function(){
  if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == "stackoverflow") {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled").siblings().removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

Without enabling non-targeted elements:

```
$("option").each(function(){
  if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == "stackoverflow") {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
});
```

Comment: No, with the value, you would use $("option[value=someval]"). He's looking for the value, not the text inside.

Comment: Ah, good point, @KyleButt. I've updated my solution. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Disabling the options with “stackoverflow” doesn’t imply to enable those without “stackoverflow”.

Comment: @Gumbo: Correct. I was trying anticipate future problems, but I can see how my solution would cause more problems, such as if the user had *other* options disabled by default. I've updated my solution. Thanks for pointing out my error.

Comment: `op[i].disabled = (op[i].value.toLowerCase() == "stackoverflow")` ;) +1

Comment: Another improvement would be that if we are disabling the currently selected option we should move the selection too. Surprisingly the latest version of firefox which I use for development does not do it automatically, I would've expected it to do it.

Comment: Some of the other answers show better options for pure JS. Notably the use of array.find() and querySelector()

Answer (score 5):

Set an `id` to the `option` then use `getElementById` and disable it when `x` value has been selected, like so:

```
<body>
      <select class="pull-right text-muted small" 
                 name="driveCapacity" id=driveCapacity onchange="checkRPM()">
      <option value="4000.0" id="4000">4TB</option>
      <option value="900.0" id="900">900GB</option>
      <option value="300.0" id ="300">300GB</option>
    </select>
    </body>
<script>
var perfType = document.getElementById("driveRPM").value;
if(perfType == "7200"){         
        document.getElementById("driveCapacity").value = "4000.0";
        document.getElementById("4000").disabled = false;           
    }else{          
        document.getElementById("4000").disabled = true;            
    }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a straightforward selector:

`document.querySelector('select[name="theName"] option[value="theValue"]').disabled = true;`

Answer (score 3):

Here with JQuery, if anybody search it:

```
var vals = new Array( 2, 3, 5, 8 );
select_disable_options('add_reklamaciq_reason',vals);
select_disable_options('add_reklamaciq_reason');

function select_disable_options(selectid,vals){
  var selected = false ;
  $('#'+selectid+' option').removeAttr('selected');
  $('#'+selectid+' option').each(function(i,elem){
       var elid = parseInt($(elem).attr('value'));
       if(vals){
           if(vals.indexOf(elid) != -1){
               $(elem).removeAttr('disabled');
               if(selected == false){
                   $(elem).attr('selected','selected');
                   selected = true ; 
               }
           }else{
               $(elem).attr('disabled','disabled'); 
           }
       }else{
            $(elem).removeAttr('disabled');
       }
  });   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason other answers are unnecessarily complex, it's easy to do it in one line in pure JavaScript:

```
Array.prototype.find.call(selectElement.options, o => o.value === optionValue).disabled = true;
```

or

```
selectElement.querySelector('option[value="'+optionValue.replace(/["\\]/g, '\\$&')+'"]').disabled = true;
```

The performance depends on the number of the options (the more the options, the slower the first one) and whether you can omit the [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830519/what-all-needs-escaping-in-queryselector) (the `replace` call) from the second one. Also the first one uses `Array.find` and arrow functions that are not available in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give you also the idea to disable an `<option>` with a given defined value (`not innerhtml`). I recommend to it with `jQuery` to get the simplest way. See my sample below.

***HTML***

```
Status:  
<div id="option">
   <select class="status">
      <option value="hand" selected>Hand</option>
      <option value="simple">Typed</option>
      <option value="printed">Printed</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

***Javascript***

The idea here is how to disable `Printed` option when current `Status` is `Hand`

```
var status = $('#option').find('.status');//to get current the selected value
var op = status.find('option');//to get the elements for disable attribute
(status.val() == 'hand')? op[2].disabled = true: op[2].disabled = false;
```

You may see how it works here:

https://jsfiddle.net/chetabahana/f7ejxhnk/28/

Answer (score -4):

You can also use this function,

```
function optionDisable(selectId, optionIndices)
{
    for (var idxCount=0; idxCount<optionIndices.length;idxCount++)
    {
        document.getElementById(selectId).children[optionIndices[idxCount]].disabled="disabled";
        document.getElementById(selectId).children[optionIndices[idxCount]].style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
        document.getElementById(selectId).children[optionIndices[idxCount]].style.color = '#f00';
    }
}
```

Comment: I formatted the code, but the other hideosities of this function are on you to fix.  :P