# What chars needs escaping in querySelector?

Tags: javascript, css

According to the document here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector#Notes

It says some characters need to be escaped when doing querySelector:

> To match ID or selectors that do not follow the CSS syntax (by using a
>   colon or space inappropriately for example), you must escape the
>   character with a back slash. As the backslash is an escape character
>   in JavaScript, if you are entering a literal string, you must escape
>   it twice (once for the JavaScript string, and another time for
>   querySelector):

I was hoping to write a function that does the escaping on a string but needed to know which chars needed escaping first.

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Updated answer:

In a comment below you said:

> The thing is Im making a firefox addon Im doing is identifying items by the attribute in `label` (cuz class is same for all items). and so `querySelector('[label="blah blah blah"]')` and the user can edit the label, so thats where the problem comes in, users can make it anything.

Ah, that changes everything. A completely different set of rules applies for the operand in an attribute selector. As you're using `"` to surround the operand, I think you just have to escape the `"` with a backslash (and of course, escape any backslashes with a backslash), e.g. the *selector* (not the string for `querySelector`, we'll come back to that) for a `label` with the text `testing "one" two three` would be `[label="testing \"one\" two three"]`. So starting with a variable containing the target label, we'd replace all `"` characters with `\"` and all `\` characters with `\\`:

```
var div = document.querySelector('[label="' + theLabel.replace(/["\\]/g, '\\$&') + '"]');
```

Full example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/boxowiyo/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Escaping attributes</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div label='testing "one" \two three'>This should turn green</div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var label = 'testing "one" \\two three';
      var div = document.querySelector('[label="' + label.replace(/["\\]/g, '\\$&') + '"]');
      div.style.color = "green";
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Original answer:

Full details in [the CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/); for instance, the details for what characters in ID and class selectors need escaping is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier):

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and ISO 10646 characters `U+00A0` and higher, plus the hyphen (`-`) and the underscore (`_`); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "`B&W?`" may be written as "`B\&W\?`" or "`B\26 W\3F`".

Now, the thing about `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll` is that since they take a string, and backslashes are special in string literals, you have to use *two* backslashes in a string literal to have *one* backslash in your CSS selector. So for the last example in the quote, suppose you wanted to use that as a class selector. You'd have to do this:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".B\\26 W\\3F");
```

...which passes the selector `.B\26 W\3F` into the selector engine. [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/marazahi/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/marazahi/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks very much man for this reply. Is there anyway I can convert a string to be querySelector safe? Is there a pre-written function out there do you know by any chance?

Comment: @Noitidart: I don't know of one. You could use a regular expression to escape relevant characters, but it won't be perfect. I just tend to stick with simple `id` and `class` values that only use `a-zA-Z`, `0-9`, and `-`; then I don't have to worry about escaping.

Comment: The thing is Im making a firefox addon Im doing is identifying items by the attribute in label (cuz class is same for all items). and so `querySelector('[label="blah blah blah"]')` and the user can edit the label, so thats where the problem comes in, users can make it anything. :( lol

Comment: @Noitidart: Ah, in that case completely different rules apply -- and life probably gets a bit easier. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Superb man thanks very much I really appreciate this hard work. So basically just double quotes and forward slashes need the escaping huh. The mdn article says, and i experienced it, i need to use like 4 slashes instead of just one.

Comment: @Noitidart: Backslashes, not forward slashes. And: Doh! How could I have done the bit escaping quotes without realizing that (naturally) you have to escape the escapes? I've fixed the code above to handle both.

Answer (score 14):

If it is possible, you can use this solution, albeit not cross-browser (all modern browsers except IE) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape

```
CSS.escape(".foo#bar") ->"\.foo\#bar"
```