# how to find element that attribute include back slash [\] with attribute selectors

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-selectors

I have an html Element like this:

```
<img src="safe-file://E:\2021\07\vhi9TKXoiaF7GOOQc0Z6o7nK.png" 
          data-id="safe-file://E:\2021\07\vhi9TKXoiaF7GOOQc0Z6o7nK.png"
          class="comic-img"
          data-v-d2c79dce>
```

I want to find it by `document.querySelector('[data-id="safe-file://E:\2021\07\vhi9TKXoiaF7GOOQc0Z6o7nK.png"]')`

But this didn't work, anybody know why and how to find it by file name?

I can find img Element by

```
document.querySelector('[data-id*="2021"]')
```

but I can't find it by

```
document.querySelector('[data-id*="2021\07"]')
```

It seems that any attribute selector with `\` can't find element I want.

Comment: This might answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830519/what-chars-needs-escaping-in-queryselector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `\` needs to be double escaped. Replace each `\` with `\\5c` , or `\\\\`, so what you need is

`document.querySelector('[data-id="safe-file://E:\\5c 2021\\5c 07\\5c vhi9TKXoiaF7GOOQc0Z6o7nK.png"]')`

or

`document.querySelector('[data-id="safe-file://E:\\\\2021\\\\07\\\\vhi9TKXoiaF7GOOQc0Z6o7nK.png"]')`

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('[data-id="safe-file://E:\\5c 2021\\5c 07\\5c vhi9TKXoiaF7GOOQc0Z6o7nK.png"]'))
```

```html
<img src="safe-file://E:\2021\07\vhi9TKXoiaF7GOOQc0Z6o7nK.png" 
          data-id="safe-file://E:\2021\07\vhi9TKXoiaF7GOOQc0Z6o7nK.png"
          class="comic-img"
          data-v-d2c79dce>
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('[data-id="safe-file://E:\\\\2021\\\\07\\\\vhi9TKXoiaF7GOOQc0Z6o7nK.png"]'))
```

```html
<img src="safe-file://E:\2021\07\vhi9TKXoiaF7GOOQc0Z6o7nK.png" 
          data-id="safe-file://E:\2021\07\vhi9TKXoiaF7GOOQc0Z6o7nK.png"
          class="comic-img"
          data-v-d2c79dce>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you. May I ask Why? Why it need `////` or `\\5c `,  not just `//`?