# Queryselector back slash x2d can't select 'xxx\x2dxxx'

Tags: javascript, html, regex

e.g

```html
<table lsdata="{1:'Ship\x2dTo\x20Location',4:true}">
</table>
```

It can't use string contains selector  `document.querySelector("table[lsdata*='Ship\x2d']")` to select DOM like image:
[image]

I read below pages but no answer

- [javascript - What chars needs escaping in querySelector? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830519/what-chars-needs-escaping-in-queryselector)
- [internationalization - Which encoding uses the \x (backslash x) prefix? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889941/which-encoding-uses-the-x-backslash-x-prefix)
- [javascript - What chars needs escaping in querySelector? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830519/what-chars-needs-escaping-in-queryselector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the `\` but in this case `\\` didn't seem to work so I tried with `\\\\` and it worked:

```js
const item = document.querySelector('table[lsdata*="Ship\\\\x2d"]')
console.log(item)
```

```html
<table lsdata="{1:'Ship\x2dTo\x20Location',4:true}">
</table>
```

Comment: It's awesome! I didn't search document about this