# jQuery disable sibling option in select menu

Tags: jquery

I have 2 select menus on the same page that have some of the same options. I need to be able to disable an option from the second select menu, if the option is the same as the selected option of the first select menu.

```
<select class="option1">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>

<select class="option2">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

So if "A" is selected on option1, I need to disable "A" on option2. I have tried numerous things to no avail. I tried using siblings, and all I managed to do was disable the entire select menu instead of a specific option. Any ideas?

Comment: And it's truly a single-select list, not a multiple select list?

Comment: Yes, it is a single-select list.

Comment: You forgot to post the jQuery that you tried. Also, what should happen if someone makes a selection from the second list first?

Comment: Well you can remove that particular option using jquery, if that is ok for you.

Comment: Here you go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155909/how-can-i-disable-an-option-in-a-select-based-on-its-value-in-javascript
Disable an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something for you (see comments in the code for an explanation on how it works):

```js
// Let's react to option1 changing
$('select.option1').change(function() {
  // Get the selected text value from option1
  var selectedValue = $('option:selected', this).text();
  // Disable option2's options based on the text value
  $('select.option2 option').prop('disabled', function() {
    return $(this).text() == selectedValue;
  });
  
  // Missing from this:
  // If option2's selection is no longer enabled, set it to the first
  // non-disabled option instead
  
}).change(); // fire the change event to handle the initial selection
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="option1">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>

<select class="option2">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nailed it! Exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your options have not value, you can find it by your content

You can do like this code:

HTML

```
<select name="" id="s1">
    <option value="">01</option>
    <option value="">02</option>
    <option value="">03</option>
    <option value="">04</option>
    <option value="">05</option>
  </select>


  <select name="" id="s2">
    <option value="">01</option>
    <option value="">02</option>
    <option value="">03</option>
    <option value="">04</option>
    <option value="">05</option>
  </select>
```

jQuery

```
$("#s1").change(function() {
  $("#s2 option").prop("disabled", false);

  var option = $(this).find("option:selected").html();
  $("#s2 option:contains('" + option + "')").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

[Look result in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/runaziducu/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: I'm downvoting because of the usage of `:contains()` and `.html()`. If each select list had an option value of `"0101"` and the user selected `"01"` in `s1`, both `"01"` and `"0101"` would be disabled in the second list. Secondly, `<option>` elements don't normally have HTML for values or text.