# Hide option from dropdown 2 when selected in dropdown 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdowns, both have the same items in them. If an option is selected in dropdown 1 then I would like to hide that option in dropdown 2. When it is unselected in dropdown 1 I would like it to appear again in dropdown 2 and whichever option is then selected to then be hidden in dropdown 2. I am trying to have this exclude the blank option in the first index.

Here is a codepen that I started, but I am not sure where to go from here:

http://codepen.io/cavanflynn/pen/EjreJK

```
    var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='dropdown1']");
    var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='dropdown2']");

    $dropdown1.change(function () {
        var selectedItem = $($dropdown1).find("option:selected").val;
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't hide `<option>` tag , it doesn't work cross browser. Choices are disable or remove

Comment: Is there any way I could hide just the Text (The whole line, so it doesn't appear as a blank line in the dropdown)

Comment: Disable/enable is your best best since hide doesn't work on all browsers!

Comment: not hard to store all options and filter them so they are removed/added. Hiding text won't prevent that option being selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comments, one of the options is to disable/enable options according to the selection in the first select, like  below. This would work on all browsers as opposed to hide/show which doesn't.

```js
var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='dropdown1']");
var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='dropdown2']");

$dropdown1.change(function() {
    $dropdown2.find('option').prop("disabled", false);
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();
    if (selectedItem) {
        $dropdown2.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dropdown1">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>

<select name="dropdown2">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
```

Another option is to remove/add options in the 2nd dropdown based on the selection in the first via [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/), as below.

```
var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='dropdown1']");
var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='dropdown2']");

$dropdown1.change(function() {
    $dropdown2.empty().append($dropdown1.find('option').clone());
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();
    if (selectedItem) {
        $dropdown2.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').remove();
    }
});
```

[**A Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/vrLr9wyg/)

Comment: Just what I needed. Only thing if the first option is not blank. In that case, it doesn't work. As it works with the "change" trigger. Adding this extra line of code solves it.` var a = $("#dropdown1 option:selected").val();
$('#dropdown2').find('option[value=' + a + ']').hide();`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='dropdown1']");
var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='dropdown2']");
$dropdown1.change(function() {
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();
    var $options = $("select[name='dropdown1'] > option").clone();  
    $("select[name='dropdown2']").html($options);
    $("select[name='dropdown2'] > option[value="+selectedItem+"]").remove();  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dropdown1">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>

<select name="dropdown2">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxas38rh/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use this plugin http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js

It has some really nice callbacks and customisation options.

When one changes you can put it in the callback to update the other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it. You do need to include jQuery, and then as long as the value isn't empty hide the option with the similar value.

```js
var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='dropdown1']");
var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='dropdown2']");

$dropdown1.change(function() {
  $dropdown2.children().show();
  var selectedItem = $($dropdown1).val();
  if (selectedItem != "")
    $('select[name="dropdown2"] option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').hide();
});
 $dropdown2.change(function() {
  $dropdown1.children().show();
  var selectedItem = $($dropdown2).val();
  if (selectedItem != "")
    $('select[name="dropdown1"] option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dropdown1">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>

<select name="dropdown2">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: hide does not work cross browser ... try this code in IE for example. Will fail

Comment: don't use IE, windows has moved on, and FF and Chrome both work

Comment: trust me...this will not work in some browsers...try safari. There are 100's of similar posts about this on SO

Comment: you can use remove() instead of hide() but for that you need to create selection box dynamically.

Comment: I know it won't work on all browsers, its impossible to please everyone though, even with pure html, so one solution that works on two main browsers should be satisfactory, look at http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp to see that about 80% of people use FF or Chrome

Comment: but it's not hard to do this for 100% coverage either. This is not a new issue, been around for years,  and trying to re-invent the wheel doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that stores a set of the options on page load then filters the alternate select when a change is made. It works in both directions for changes made to either select

```
var $drops = $('.drop'),
// store a set of options
$options = $drops.eq(1).children().clone();

$drops.change(function(){
    var $other = $drops.not(this),
        otherVal = $other.val(),
        newVal = $(this).val(),
        $opts = $options.clone().filter(function(){
           return this.value !== newVal; 
        })
     $other.html($opts).val(otherVal);    
});
```

Values will also be maintained and this is 2 directional so a change in either will filter the other

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1wfzz61v/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Well, this code will find option by value in necessary selects and remove it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVqgbO

```js
var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='dropdown1']");
var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='dropdown2']");

var populateDropdown = function(element) {
  element.find("option").remove();
  element.append("<option></option>");
  // There should be real data
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    element.append("<option value='" + i + "'>Test " + i + "</option>");
  }
}

var getOptionProps = function(element) {
  var selectedValue = element.val();
  var selectedText = element.find("option[value=" + selectedValue + "]").text();
  return { text: selectedText, value: selectedValue };
}

var removeOptionWithValue = function(element, value) {
  element.find("option[value='" + value + "']").remove();
}

$dropdown1.on("change", function () {
  var selectedProps = getOptionProps($(this));
  populateDropdown($dropdown2);
  removeOptionWithValue($dropdown2, selectedProps.value);
});

$dropdown2.on("change", function () {
  var selectedProps = getOptionProps($(this));
  populateDropdown($dropdown1);
  removeOptionWithValue($dropdown1, selectedProps.value);
});
```