# how to substract options two related selects html

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i have 3 units available and two selects hhtml to select the quantity, how can i do that when the client select 1 unit (option value=1) for example in the first select, this option will substract in the second select, and this only show the remaining units? ie, the second select only will show 1 unit (option value=1) and 2 units (option value=2).I dont need show and hide. i need that if the client select one unit in the first select, in the second can only select 2 more. the options value refers to quantity

```
<select class="quantity" name="double room">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option
<option value="3">3</option
</select>
<p>
<select class="quantity" name="double room">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option
<option value="3">3</option
</select>
```

Comment: So if the user selected "1" in the firs `select` then remove (1) option in the second `select`. And if they select "2" then remove (2) options in the second? Maybe create a picture or example output

Comment: Should it get put back if they change their selection in the first select?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide option from dropdown 2 when selected in dropdown 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860103/hide-option-from-dropdown-2-when-selected-in-dropdown-1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution, hopefully it will point you in the right direction. This doesn't do anything fancy like preserve order, only removes and returns options on the second select.

https://jsfiddle.net/jpbjd40s/2/

```
// Intialize this value with the option missing from #two
var previousValue = 1;

// Do stuff on change.
$('#one').on('change', function() {

    // Put the unselected option from #one back in #two.
    $('#two').append('<option value="' + previousValue + '">' + previousValue + '</option>');

    // Remember what we had.
    previousValue = $('#one').val();

    // Remove the option from #two selected in #one.
    $('#two').children('[value="' + $('#one').val() + '"]').remove();

});
```

Comment: It would probably be better to use `.hide()`, then you can easily restore it if the user changes the first selection.

Comment: I agree, hide and show would be better... like I said it was quick :)

Comment: Although with show and hide, the select retains the hidden value until you change it. I was going to update the jsfiddle, but it seems like it would be a bit longer (at least my implementation is).

Comment: thank you for your coments and your solvings. I dont need show and hide. i need that if the client select one unit in the first select, in the second can only select 2 more. the options value refers to quantity