# one player table - two team dropdowns - how to get no double players (mysql,php,ajax)

Tags: php, mysql, dropdown

I've got one player table where all players are stored.
When I'll will select the players for the home-team and the away-team. I've got two different sql queries on the player table.

```
 <? 
  $select_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $player_table_2016 WHERE active = 1 ORDER by tname ASC"); 
   echo "<select data-placeholder='Spieler auswählen...' class='chosen-select' style='width:220px;' multiple tabindex='4' name='homespieler[]' required>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_query)) {
      echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>" .$row['tname']."</option>";
     </option>";
    }
echo "</select>";      
?>
```

after that I select the away-team with another query:

```
$select_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $player_table_2016 WHERE active = 1 ORDER by tname ASC"); 
   echo "<select data-placeholder='Spieler auswählen...' class='chosen-select' style='width:220px;' multiple tabindex='4' name='awayspieler[]' required>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_query)) {
      echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>" .$row['tname']."</option>";
    </option>";
    }
echo "</select>";
```

The problem is, that I'm not able to check in the away-team selection, if a player is already selected for home-team. It would be great to choose in the away-team only those players, who aren't alreay in the home-team.

How can this be possible?

Comment: Your queries are exactly the same. You need to show us the columns of your player table to get a good answer.

Comment: You want to exclude the selection of the first player in the second dropdown, right?

Comment: @blckbird: Yes I want to exclude the selection of the first players in the second dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript Solution with one page**

After the selection of your home player you need to trigger an event to exclude the player from the second drop down. You can do this with JavaScript for example.

In your selects add an ID like this:

```
<select id='homeTeamPlayer'>
<select id='awayTeamPlayer'>
```

In your first `<select>` add a javascript method `onchange` like this:

```
<select onchange="excludePlayer()">
```

This method shall then disable the option in the second drop down:

```
function excludePlayer() {
    var homeTeamPlayerId= document.getElementById("homeTeamPlayer").value
    // Get all options within <select id='homeTeamPlayer'>...</select>
    var op = document.getElementById("awayTeamPlayer").getElementsByTagName("option");
    for (var i = 0; i < op.length; i++) {
      // lowercase comparison for case-insensitivity
      (op[i].value == homeTeamPlayerId) 
        ? op[i].disabled = true 
        : op[i].disabled = false ;
    }
}
```

(copied the disable code from here: [How can I disable an <option> in a <select> based on its value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155909/how-can-i-disable-an-option-in-a-select-based-on-its-value-in-javascript))

You should also implement this for the second drop down.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script>
  function excludePlayer() {
   var homeTeamPlayerId= document.getElementById("homeTeamPlayer").value
   // Get all options within <select id='homeTeamPlayer'>...</select>
   var op = document.getElementById("awayTeamPlayer").getElementsByTagName("option");
   for (var i = 0; i < op.length; i++) {
     // lowercase comparison for case-insensitivity
     (op[i].value == homeTeamPlayerId) 
    ? op[i].disabled = true
    : op[i].disabled = false ;
   }
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <select id='homeTeamPlayer' onchange="excludePlayer()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
 </select>
 <select id='awayTeamPlayer'>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
 </select>
</html>
```

**SQL Solution with two pages**

On your first you have one dropdown to select the home team player.
The created HTML should look like this:

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
    <select data-placeholder='Spieler auswählen...' class='chosen-select' style='width:220px;' multiple tabindex='4' name='homespieler' required>
        <option ...> ... </option>
        <option ...> ... </option>
    </select>
    <input type=submit />
</form>
```

On your second page you can now get the value of the selected home player like this: `$POST_['homespieler']`

You can you this in your query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM $player_table_2016 
WHERE active = 1 
AND ID != $POST_['homespieler']
ORDER by name ASC
```

Comment: your query will return 0 results

Comment: @blckbird: Thanks for your support and idea. But how do I implement/integrate the JS disable part in the away team sql query?

Comment: You can't do this on the same page. Because at the time you fire your sql, you do not know which selection the user will make. Therefore, I suggest to simply disable the respective `<option>`

Comment: @blckbird: Thanks for your answer again. I`m trying to run the javascript one page version but it doesn't work. I`ve put in the js function in the body and also named the select IDs and pasted in the onChange. It is still possible to choose players for awayTeam which are already chosen for homeTeam. Thanks for your support.

Comment: But the one page javascript version still does'nt work for me. :( 

Console says: ReferenceError: homeTeamPlayerId is not defined
 

(op[i].value == homeTeamPlayerId)

Comment: Need more details to help you further. Is the JS executed at all?

Comment: With my updated code, *this* error should no longer occur. So let me know if theres somethinge else not working yet.

Comment: Ah there was an typing error. So, now I don't recieve any error msg but it still doesn't work. It is still possible to choose players for awayTeam which are already chosen for homeTeam. The disable function doesn't work, I think.

Comment: Ok. I`ve to look one step deeper. I use https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ for the select dropdown. And maybe this is the problem, why it's not working.

Comment: I gave you this solution and its working. You need to implement it in your code now. Please up vote and accept as answer.

Comment: But in your code also multiple select doesn't work. Thanks for your support and suggestion, but it isn't working in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax for such scenarios.
Once user selects all the players for home team use jQuerys `.blur` event and pass all the id's to php.
And than you can use query
`select * from table where id not in ($id)` where $id is value received through POST or GET method

Comment: Can you please share more detailied information, how this solution should be implemented? Thanks

Comment: Detailed information is really helpful, you're totally right Rene. I bet that's why people left you comments on your question asking *you* to be more clear and informative on the question itself