# jQuery disable other dropdown values based on selected value of other dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have in my website 3 dropdowns and every dropdown has 8 options (1 to 8).
My goal is to disable the dropdown options based on what you've already selected in the other dropdowns, the total sum is maximum 8. So for example if you select 4 in the first dropdown you can only select 1 to 4 in the other 2 dropdowns.

If you select 8 in the first you can't select anything else from the others.

This is what I've tried:

```
$(".options select").change(function() {
  var value1 = $("#input_1_5").val();
  var value2 = $("#input_1_6").val();
  var value3 = $("#input_1_7").val();
  var sum = parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2) + parseInt(value3);
  var rest = 9-sum;

  $("#input_1_6 > option").slice(rest,9).each(function() {
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    });

  var rest2 = rest - 9
  $("#input_1_7 > option").slice(rest2,9).each(function() {
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    });
});
```

The problem with this is that it only work the first time you select something, unfortunately.

EDIT: jsfiddle update https://jsfiddle.net/k7krx87L/4/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a PLUNKR of the work done till now.

Comment: @SatejS here's a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k7krx87L/1/

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155909/how-can-i-disable-an-option-in-a-select-based-on-its-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You would use the following selector:

```
$("#input_1_6 option:gt(4)").prop("disabled", true);
```

This means disable all options in element with id #input_1_6 starting from 5th, the selector [gt(4)](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) means elements from index 4, indexes start from 0 in DOM.

Comment: This should be very helpful.

Comment: But how can I make the 4 in the gt(4) dynamic?

Comment: Declare a variable `var index = [calculate your index here, or hardcoded];$("#input_1_6 option:gt("+index+")").prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: I've tried this, doesn't seem to work, unfortunately

Comment: @MaposaTakalani can you check out my fiddle and see how I can fix my problem that it only works the first you select a value. It doesn't work when you want to switch values https://jsfiddle.net/k7krx87L/5/

Comment: well, the logic for your project I can't solve, but that's how you disable options the way you described it @FrankLucas

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function () {


    $('#input_1_5').on('change', function (){
        var input_1_5 = $(this).val();
        var input_1_6 = $('#input_1_6').val();
        var input_1_7 = $('#input_1_7').val();
        var cur_val;
        cur_val=parseInt(input_1_5)+parseInt(input_1_6)+parseInt(input_1_7);
        for(i=1;i<=8;i++)
        {
            if((i+parseInt(cur_val))<=8)
            {
                 $('#input_1_6').children('option[value="' + i + '"]').attr('disabled', false);
                 $('#input_1_7').children('option[value="' + i + '"]').attr('disabled', false);
            }
            else
            {
                 $('#input_1_6').children('option[value="' + i + '"]').attr('disabled', true);
                 $('#input_1_7').children('option[value="' + i + '"]').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        }
    });
    $('#input_1_6').on('change', function (){
        var input_1_5 = $('#input_1_5').val();
        var input_1_6 = $(this).val();
        var input_1_7 = $('#input_1_7').val();
        var cur_val;
        cur_val=parseInt(input_1_5)+parseInt(input_1_6)+parseInt(input_1_7);
        for(i=1;i<=8;i++)
        {
            if((i+parseInt(cur_val))<=8)
            {
                 $('#input_1_5').children('option[value="' + i + '"]').attr('disabled', false);
                 $('#input_1_7').children('option[value="' + i + '"]').attr('disabled', false);
            }
            else
            {
                 $('#input_1_5').children('option[value="' + i + '"]').attr('disabled', true);
                 $('#input_1_7').children('option[value="' + i + '"]').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        }
    }); 
    $('#input_1_7').on('change', function (){
        var input_1_5 = $('#input_1_5').val();
        var input_1_6 = $('#input_1_6').val();
        var input_1_7 = $(this).val();
        var cur_val;
        cur_val=parseInt(input_1_5)+parseInt(input_1_6)+parseInt(input_1_7);
        for(i=1;i<=8;i++)
        {
            if((i+parseInt(cur_val))<=8)
            {
                 $('#input_1_5').children('option[value="' + i + '"]').attr('disabled', false);
                 $('#input_1_6').children('option[value="' + i + '"]').attr('disabled', false);
            }
            else
            {
                 $('#input_1_5').children('option[value="' + i + '"]').attr('disabled', true);
                 $('#input_1_6').children('option[value="' + i + '"]').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        }
    });

 });
</script>

 <select name="" id="input_1_5">
     <option value="0">0</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="7">7</option>
     <option value="8">8</option>
 </select>
 <select name="" id="input_1_6">
     <option value="0">0</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="7">7</option>
     <option value="8">8</option>
 </select>
 <select name="" id="input_1_7">
     <option value="0">0</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="7">7</option>
     <option value="8">8</option>
 </select>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Whoa this looks like a lot of code for something relative simple, I'll try it out and try to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='project_manager[]']");
        var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='test_engineer[]']");
        var $dropdown3 = $("select[name='viewer[]']");

        $dropdown1.change(function() {
            $dropdown2.empty().append($dropdown1.find('option').clone());
            $dropdown3.empty().append($dropdown2.find('option').clone());
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            if (selectedItem) {
                $dropdown2.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
                $dropdown3.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });

        $dropdown2.change(function() {
            $dropdown3.empty().append($dropdown2.find('option').clone());
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            if (selectedItem) {
                $dropdown3.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <select name="project_manager[]">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>

<select name="test_engineer[]"  >
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
<select name="viewer[]" >
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
  <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: "vrLr9wyg"
      }], "*")
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```