# Disable all select option depend upon array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

i have an multi select box given below:
Please First see that.

My code:

```
$("select option:contains( " + data + ")").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

only helps to disable select option only if data has only one value(not in array)

Here is the problem:

```
var data =  31/8/2018,30/9/2018


I want to disable select options having values == data ,
```

so maybe, we need a loop which check data[1] == first  option then second then third etc
if values matched, that value will be disabled.

then check data[2] == first option then second then third ...etc
if values matched, that select option will be disabled.

Result:: Ex. First two option ll be disable
Is that Possible

```
<select class="form-control" multiple="" name="month[]" id="month">
 <option value="31/8/2018">  1 @ 31/8/2018   </option>
 <option value="30/9/2018">  2 @ 30/9/2018   </option>
 <option value="31/10/2018"> 3 @ 31/10/2018  </option>
 <option value="30/11/2018"> 4 @ 30/11/2018  </option>
 <option value="31/12/2018"> 5 @ 31/12/2018  </option>
</select>

$("select option:contains( " + data + ")").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Comment: Can you explain what the variable `data` looks like and where it's being set?

Comment: Actually looks like:    var data = <?php echo json_encode($existing_month) ?>;    Looks as:    31/8/2018,30/9/2018 in database

Comment: possible duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155909/how-can-i-disable-an-option-in-a-select-based-on-its-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming data is a valid JavaScript array you can iterate each value and disable the `option` that contains that value.

```js
// <?php echo json_encode($existing_month);
var data = "31/8/2018,30/9/2018";

$.each(data.split(','), function(index, value) {
  $('select > option').filter(function () {
   return $(this).val() == value
  }).prop('disabled', true)
})
```

```css
option[disabled] {
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: not-allowed
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" multiple="" name="month[]" id="month">
   <option value="31/8/2018">  1 @ 31/8/2018   </option>
   <option value="30/9/2018">  2 @ 30/9/2018   </option>
   <option value="31/10/2018"> 3 @ 31/10/2018  </option>
   <option value="30/11/2018"> 4 @ 30/11/2018  </option>
   <option value="31/12/2018"> 5 @ 31/12/2018  </option>
</select>
```

**EDIT:** From your comment it appears your variable is a comma delimited string  so we will need to split the string by using the comma as the delimiter which results in an array.

Comment: It Works Fine   Thanks,         but my database contain Like:  31/8/2018,30/9/2018                    Not Like:  '31/8/2018','30/9/2018'     Can u do something                 Actually i am new to java script So...

Comment: In your php `json_encode($existing_month)` is `$existing_month` an array or string or...?

Comment: An array, which are inserted by Selecting multi select box, then use implode(',', $_POST['month']);   function.

Comment: So the raw value is actually a comma delimited string that looks like `31/8/2018,30/9/2018` when echo'd from PHP? That's fine. I'll update the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), "contains" can only be text. One quick answer with JQuery is to just iterate over the array using the same logic.

```js
const data = ["31/8/2018", "30/9/2018"]
data.forEach(entry => {
  $("select option:contains( " + entry + ")").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" multiple="" name="month[]" id="month">
  <option value="31/8/2018"> 1 @ 31/8/2018 </option>
  <option value="30/9/2018"> 2 @ 30/9/2018 </option>
  <option value="31/10/2018"> 3 @ 31/10/2018 </option>
  <option value="30/11/2018"> 4 @ 30/11/2018 </option>
  <option value="31/12/2018"> 5 @ 31/12/2018 </option>
</select>
```