# Drop down disable the options but display the options available

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have a drop down and I need disable the options, but user can display the drop-down menu and see the options available but the user cannot select none.

```html
<select name="list" disabled="disabled" id="list">
    <option value="1">uno</option>
    <option value="2">dos</option>
    <option value="3">tre</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling each option individually would produce the desired outcome.

In the following snippet, I disabled the first two options.

```html
<select name="list"  id="list">
    <option value="1" >uno</option>
    <option value="2" >dos</option>
    <option value="3">tre</option>

</select>
<script>
    // Get all options within <select id='list'>...</select>
    var options = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("option");
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    // Disable them one by one
      options[i].disabled = true;
    }
</script>
```

The javascript part has been adapted from an an answer that you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155909/how-can-i-disable-an-option-in-a-select-based-on-its-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, in case it is a small drop down if it is functional, but in case it is something very broad, doing it one by one would be very difficult.