# Jquery/Javascript: Compare two dropdown min and max values?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two dropdowns. One has min values and the other has max values.

I'm trying to disable options from max dropdown if they are less than min values

```html
<div>
  <select id="min">
    <option>Select min</option>
    <option value=0>0</option>
    <option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
    <option value=3>3</option>
    <option value=4>4</option>
    <option value=5>5</option>
  </select>

  <select id="max">
    <option>Select max</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
    <option value=3>3</option>
    <option value=4>4</option>
    <option value=5>5</option>
    <option value=6>6</option>
    <option value=7>7</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable an <option> in a <select> based on its value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155909/how-can-i-disable-an-option-in-a-select-based-on-its-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

FYI: If you don't set the `value` attribute of an `option` element, then the `value` just becomes the text content of that `option`, so in your case, you don't need to set `value` on any of the `options`.

See additional comments inline:

```js
let maxSelect = document.getElementById("max");
let minSelect = document.getElementById("min")

// When the first select's value is changed...
minSelect.addEventListener("change", function(){

  // Loop through all the <option> elements in the second list
  maxSelect.querySelectorAll("option").forEach(function(opt){
  
    // Check the option value to see if it is more than the value
    // of the first select. If so, disable it, otherwise enable it.
    // The prepended + implicitly converts the string values to numbers
    if(+minSelect.value > +opt.value){
      opt.disabled = true;
    } else {
       opt.disabled = false;   
    }
    
  });

});
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="min">
    <option>Select min</option>
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>

  <select id="max">
    <option>Select max</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: `https://jsfiddle.net/thorstorm1102/x7zsapy2/6/` Can you check here. if Input is `101`. Wrong dropdown values are disabled

Comment: @Zanthoxylumpiperitum Oh, little bug there. We need to convert the `select` values to numbers (they are strings by default) for numeric comparisons to work. I'll update my answer.