# Use querySelectorAll to hide and disable <option> classes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to adapt a solution that I found (here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2155924/3394918) to a problem I'm having, and can't seem to get it to work. I have several automatically generated menus with select elements that need to change based on user choices. In the linked question above, the user wanted to disable options based on values, however I want to disable (and enable) them based on class. I thought it would be an easy transition, but I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The original answer:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#foo option").forEach(opt => {
    if (opt.value == "StackOverflow") {
        opt.disabled = true;
    }
});
```

What I did with it:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".models1and2Option").forEach((option) => {
  option.disabled = true;
  option.hidden = true;
});

document.querySelectorAll(".model3Option").forEach((option) => {
  option.disabled = false;
  option.hidden = false;
});
```

Where each option has a class based on which user choice (model) it corresponds to. Example:

```
<option class="model3Option" disabled hidden value="Projected Revenue: Incentive Funding">Projected Revenue: Incentive Funding</option>
```

Not only is nothing changing when I test, when I console.log() document.querySelectorAll(".model3Option") the console says the NodeList is empty (but it's not empty when I test other classes that aren't attached to option elements), so I suspect I have a major error in my assumptions on how the code should be working.

Comment: If things are being changed dynamically, depending on when your 'document.querySelectorAll' is being called, the element might not exist. 

Run your query selector while referring to an element on the page which always exists (such as a page container). e.g. document.querySelectorAll(".container .models1and2Option").forEach...

Comment: @lawrence_monk I'm actually a little confused because in theory the element should have existed when the selector was called using the prior structure, but after playing around with it for a bit and moving things around, it's working. So I believe you nailed the problem, though I can't really logic it out. Thanks for the tip.